# How to Export Mongo Data with UTC Timestamps?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to use mongoexport to export a bunch of data in json so I can read it in a different program. I use the command:

```
mongoexport --jsonArray -h some_ip -d some_db -c some_collection -o mongo_dump.json
```

Problem is, all of my datetime objects wind up coming out looking like:

```
"time_created" : { "$date" : 1344000402000 }
"time_created" : { "$date" : 1343999298000 }
```

Which is the special 64 bit mongo time format. Is there something simple I can specify to just get unixtimestamps? Mongo time is useless to me and annoying to convert from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a flag to change them in the output, unfortunately.

However, since the difference is just an extra three digits at the end, you can just do something like this:

```
sed -e 's/{ "\$date" : \([0-9]*\)[0-9]\{3\}/{ "\$date" : \1/' mongo_dump.json > unixstyle.json
```

It converted:

```
"time_created" : { "$date" : 1344000402000 }
"time_created" : { "$date" : 1343999298000 }
```

to:

```
"time_created" : { "$date" : 1344000402 }
"time_created" : { "$date" : 1343999298 }
```

**edited to fix it to handle all kinds of digits, not just 0s**

Comment: Would it always just be three digits? According to http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Timestamp+data+type, you'd need to use exactly the first 32 bits instead. That seems to usually be the same as chopping off the last three digits, but I'm thinking that wouldn't always work.

Comment: ISODate is not the same as the Timestamp data type. It uses the Date type: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dates

Comment: I tested it with some dates here, and they seemed reasonable--try it out with yours.

Comment: If you need it to handle more than one date per record, you probably have to change the sed to handle a global replace with /g